# OpenGL: for drawing multiple objects, can I input a series of data to the same fragment shader for different instances?

Tags: opengl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

The current method is to input a series of data to the same vertex shader for different instances.
See the article "[Instancing](http://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-OpenGL/Instancing)"

But how about for many instances, they share the same vertex shader, the same fragment shader,
but have some different uniform parameters ([Update] uniform variables)  both in the vertex shader and fragment shader.
For example, the vertex shader has:

```
position
```

the fragment shader has 10 parameters, and only 3 of them will change with instances:

```
7 other uniform parameters ([Update] uniform variables)  (keep the same for different instances)
colorFrequency    
lightnessAttenuationLinearParameter    
lightnessAttenuationQuadraticParameter
```

Solution 1: One workaround is:
Input all data into vertex shader, then let vertex shader pass on some parameters into fragment shader.

But I am afraid actually this is slow.
And from programming point of view, this has no good readability.

Solution 2: (It is not opengl instancing. But I draw similar objects with the same vertex shader and fragment shader)
For the first time set up of the opengl program and bind it with 10 parameters ([Update] uniform variables) with the fragment shader.
And then every time draw a new instance, only update 1 position parameter ([Update] uniform variables)  in the vertex shader, the 3 parameters ([Update] uniform variables)  in the fragment shader.
This way, even though every time it would issue a draw element command, at least it doesn't do bind and unbind stuff after the first time drawing.

My questions:
Among the two solutions, which is faster?

Is there any other better way than the two solutions?

Comment: "*The current method is to input a series of data to the same vertex shader for different instances.*" No, that's not how instancing works. Instancing provides the same per-vertex data with different per-instance data. But the different instances have different executions of the vertex shader. They use the same vertex shader code, but different vertex shader invocations.

Comment: OK, thanks. I might not phrase it in a misleading way. There is a divider, so different data are used for different instances.

Comment: "*I haven't implemented the method of using vertex instancing*" OK, so you're not using instancing at all; you're just using uniforms. At this point, it's not clear at all what you're even doing or asking about. Post some code or something.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas. 
I make it more clear: My questions: Among the two solutions, which is faster? Is there any other better way than the two solutions?
And also you have answer one question in the post: I can only pass parameters from vertex shader to fragment shader for the instance situation,

Comment: Neither "solution" is the faster way to use instancing because neither one *uses instancing*. If you are issuing a separate draw command for each instance, it's *not instancing*. If you're getting all your per-instance data purely from uniforms, with no per-instance inputs, you're not using instancing. Your question is like asking which is the fastest way to fly: walking or running. Neither, because neither one actually flies.

Comment: I revise my post. It is not OpenGL instancing. But I think this question is about instances (multiple objects). I knew the solution 2 is not OpenGL instancing. For the solution 1, since I cannot input instance data directly into fragment shader, so the workaround is through the vertex shader. Is Solution 1 an OpenGL instancing? I think so.

Comment: The first way is probably faster, because you aren't making as many draw calls and you aren't changing uniforms on the CPU all the time.

Comment: @immibis Thanks. I think it is a trade off between: (1) more draw calls in the Solution 2. (2) more data passed on from vertex shader to fragment shader, in the Solution 1.